# Good practice for keeping track of timestamps

Tags: c#, oop

What would be considered a good practice for keeping track of e.g. timestamps of received messages in an application that's doing serial communication?

Let's say the application receives streaming messages on the serial port 20 times per second.  And you want to keep track of the timestamp of the received message.  A way to do it could be like this:

```
public class SerialPortHandler {
    private DateTime _rxTimestamp;
    private SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        _rxTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
        // Collect bytes in RX buffer and do stuff...
    }
}
```

But then `_rxTimestamp` would be set to a new instance of the DateTime object every time data is received.  I know C# has garbage collection that will dispose of unreferenced objects in memory.  But is this way of doing it completely in line with good OOP practice, or could it be considered wasteful in regards to computer resources?

Comment: What do you want to use the timestamp for?

Comment: @abto Does it matter?  But for the sake of argument, let's say I'm doing asynchronous communication and need to check if a message has been received within a given time limit.

Comment: There is not any garbage collected instance (it's a value type) but the main point here IMO is accuracy (which you do not have with a plain DateTime) and UTC (which you're not using then when switching to/from DST you will have hops/holes). 20 times a second is on the edge for system time. You might use it as reference (UTC time!) together with a stopwatch

Comment: If _you want to log **each** request_ with a timestamp, then it's moot. Actually, _how_ you'd manage to persist the log is more of the (I/O) bottleneck IMHO - e.g. do I "write to some persistence layer" 20 times a second (or do I "batch")?

Comment: I was thinking to check the difference between last message received and raise some bool flag. My attempt on this                                         
  TimeSpan difference = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(_rxTimestamp);
                        if (difference.TotalSeconds > 20)

Comment: @khmub Yeah, that's how I've been doing it earlier.  Not sure if it's good practice, though...

Comment: @EdSF I agree. But my question was more related to whether it's fine overwriting the same field with a new object every 50 ms. leaving the old objects unreferenced, or if it's a little extreme and should be done in some other way.

Comment: @Oystein If it's simply for keeping track of data, the usual way would be to use an incrementing Id, for example an `Int32` that gets incremeted with `Interlocked` to ensure thread-safety. As for the "overriding an object every 50ms" - that's no problem at all.

Comment: Note that `DateTime` is a struct, so when you overwrite your field - you overwrite old value in memory, so there are no "objects left unreferenced" (not that it would be a problem anyway).

Comment: DateTime.Now returns a DateTime that is a value type, so there isn't pressure on the garbage collector by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific case is unproblematic in terms of memory usage. `System.DateTime` is [a value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) and your assignment does not involve boxing the value, so there are no objects created that the GC needs to collect. The only thing that happens is that the value of the field `_rxTimestamp` is set.

You could even argue if *creating an instance of `DateTime`* is the right terminology here. What happens is that the 64 bit value of the current date and time is put in the memory spot of `_rxTimestamp`. The old value is simply overwritten.

Comment: "I'm doing asynchronous communication and need to check if a message has been received within a given time limit". I think, this answer is not relevent with question. Questionar is aware about _rxTimestamp value is overwriting and he is looking and considering for a good solution to perform purpose.

Comment: @Rainman: You're misunderstanding the issue. OP is aware that the _reference_ gets overwritten, but is clearly (and **explicitly**) worried about the **objects that remain in memory**. The quote you are using from OP is to explain the overall purpose of the code, not the specific question.

Comment: @Sefe Good answer.  But could you also mention considerations about overwriting a field on a regular basis with a new object instance, leaving the unreferenced objects in memory?

Comment: @Oystein: What would you have me write there? Is there anything specific you want to know? The problem with this issue is that it is hard to generalize it, because it depends on factors like object size, memory and performance requirements etc.

Comment: @Sefe Well, *that*, basically. :-)  Whether overriding fields with new object instances on a regular basis is a problem or not, depends on as you say object size, memory, performance requirements etc.  I know now that in my case it's not a problem, both since DateTime is a value type, and that it in any event is just 64 bits 20 times per second.  I just think that writing that considerations have to be made about x, y and z would add good value to the answer.

Comment: @Oystein: It's hard to generalize an answer to a specific question. I'm not opposed to extending my answer, I just don't know how, without making it either too long or too unprecise.